# How can i put my buttons like that?

Tags: android, layout

[image]

I want to put my number button like that. This is my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
        titleView.setText("Hello World!");
        layout.addView(titleView);

        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);
        android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

        Button btnConnect = new Button(this);
        btnConnect.setText("Connect");
        btnConnect.setLayoutParams(param);
        layout2.addView(btnConnect);

        Button btnDisconnect = new Button(this);
        btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
        layout2.addView(btnDisconnect);
        btnDisconnect.setLayoutParams(param);


        layout.addView(layout2);

        TableLayout tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tblLayout.setOrientation(TableLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TableRow tblrow = null;



        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 1) {
                tblrow = new TableRow(this);
                tblLayout.addView(tblrow);

            }

            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("" + i);
            tblrow.addView(b);
        }




        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        Button btnZero = new Button(this);
        btnZero.setText("0");
        Button btnHash = new Button(this);
        btnHash.setText("#");
        Button btnStar = new Button(this);
        btnStar.setText("*");
        tr.addView(btnZero);
        tr.addView(btnHash);
        tr.addView(btnStar);
        tblLayout.addView(tr);




        layout.addView(tblLayout);
        setContentView(layout);
```

this complies:

[image]

In order to make my columns like that. I used this code:

```
android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);
tblLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

but there's no change. What do i need to do? Is that Layoutparams not enough to do that?

Comment: You can put a layout in a layout. You could for example lay the top buttons with a `LinearLayout`, horizontally and the rest with the `GridLayout`.

Comment: yeah you are right by i need to use TableLayout. This is must

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this in a XML file? Seems like overkill to dynamically create this in code.

Comment: yeap i know i have to do with dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the widths of `layout`, `layout2`, `tblLayout`, each `tblRow`, and `tr` to `MATCH_PARENT` and each Button must have an equal `layout_weight`.

Comment: LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1 last 1 is width isn't it but not working